# return value of function is a string in C

Tags: c

I made some code in C with two functions.

One functions looks for a word (group of characters) and then saves it to a string. The other function shows what's inside the string. I can't find the right way to save the returning value to a string.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char SchrijfString(void);
void LeesString(char);

int main(void)
{
    char x[60];
    x = SchrijfString(x);
    LeesString(x);
    return 0;
}

char SchrijfString(char x[])
{
    printf("geef een string in: \n");
    gets(x);
    return x;
}

void LeesString(char x[])
{
    printf("In de string zit:\n %s", x);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: never use `gets`

Comment: `x = SchrijfString(x);` Since `x` itself has been updated, there is no need to write back. --> `SchrijfString(x);`, `char SchrijfString(char x[])` --> `char *SchrijfString(char x[])`

Comment: In `char x[60]; x = SchrijfString(x);` you can't do that: you already defined that `x` is an array. Use a pointer type as the last comment.

Comment: The `return` in `SchrijfString()` returns the wrong type; it returns a `char *`, but the function signature says it returns a single `char`.  In context, there's not much virtue in returning the `char *` since it is simply the value you passed into the function.  You don't even return NULL if `gets()` -- which you shouldn't be using anyway -- indicates EOF.

Comment: I would encourage your to hand over the "code" to a C compiler. When it the compiler stops complaining please improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `gets` function is already populating `x` with a string specified by the user, so no need to return anything from `SchrijfString` or to assign anything to `x` back in main.  Your function prototypes don't match the definitions.  They need to be the same.

Also, `gets` is deprecated because it is unsafe.  Use `fgets` instead.

```
void SchrijfString(char x[], int len);
void  LeesString(char x[]);

int main(void)
{
    char x[60];
    SchrijfString(x, sizeof(x));
    LeesString(x);
    return 0;
}

void SchrijfString(char x[], int len)
{
    printf("geef een string in: \n");
    fgets(x, len, stdin);
}
```

Comment: See [Why `gets()` is so dangerous it should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: `fgets` is not just a drop-in replacement for `gets`. It's safer, but unlike `gets` it leaves the trailing `'\n'` in the target array.